# How do I return multiple fields in a MongoDB aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of MongoDB documents that look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : "123",
        "created_by": "bob",
        "date_added": ISODate("2014-08-27T17:43:23Z"),
        "size": "XL",
        "color": "red"
}
```

The question I'm trying to answer is: *What is the color of the item most recently added by each person?*

I've gotten this far:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: { who: "$created_by"}, added: { $max: "$date_added" } } },
])

{ "_id" : { "who" : "bob" }, "added" : ISODate("2014-09-30T07:06:38.135Z") }
{ "_id" : { "who" : "mike" }, "added" : ISODate("2014-09-30T07:10:03.098Z") }
{ "_id" : { "who" : "mary" }, "added" : ISODate("2014-09-30T07:07:27.787Z") }
{ "_id" : { "who" : "john" }, "added" : ISODate("2014-09-30T07:09:51.418Z") }
```

However, it only returns the user's name and the date of when the document was added.  I can't figure out how to get the query to also return the color.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.

```
db.stuff.aggregate([ {
    $sort : {
        date_added : -1
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            who : "$created_by"
        },
        added : {
            $first : "$date_added"
        },
        color : {
            $first : "$color"
        }
    }
} ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, this doesn't produce the correct result. Changing the `$first` operator to `$last` for the `color` field should produce the same document (since I'm only wanting the color from the most recently added doc), but it doesn't.

Comment: @jamieb, Sorry that I made a spell mistake one `$sort : {data_added : -1}`. It should be `$sort : {date_added : -1}`.